# SCVMM 2012 SP1 migration Error 2911

Tags: scvmm

When trying to migrate a VM Guest from one cluster to another the Live Migration fails with Error 2911. There are insufficient resources available on host. There are 500GB of RAM free, 2TB of storage and 64 logical processors free on this test box with 1 vm guest.                           How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2869591) "This can occur if Windows Management Framework (WMF) 3.0 is installed on Hyper-V host without also applying update 2781512."

The Microsoft article goes on to advise installing hotfix 2781512.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Kate. The KB article you mentioned will only work with Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V hosts.
Note: the article you mention is to get McAfee working with Hyper-V so I guessed this was the issue.
But it pointed me in the right direction.

I did find the solution was based on turning off Mcafee Antivirus.